# Async/Await nested try/catch

Tags: node.js, try-catch

I have two similiar functions foo and bar that looks like this

```
async function foo() {
    try {
        await postRequest() 
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }

async function bar() {
    try {
        await anotherReq() 
    } catch (error) {
        // handle error
    }
```

I want to call foo first, handle the error by calling bar, then handle eventual bar errors again.

So i tried to do this

```
try {
    await foo();
} catch (error) {
    try {
        await bar()
    } catch(error) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

But it's obviously ugly because of the nesting.
Any workaround ?

Comment: Are you familiar with ```recursion```? use recursion concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do with `async/await` to avoid the nesting is to return tupels of `[result, error]` instead of `try/catch` blocks.

So in this case my code would look something like this:

```
async function foo() {
  const response = await postRequest();

  if (response.ok) {
    return  [response, null];
  }

  return [null, "error"];
}

async function bar() {
  const response = await anotherReq();

  if (response.ok) {
    return  [response, null];
  }

  return [null, "error"];
}

// call functions
const [res, err] = await foo();

if (err) {
  const [res, err] = await bar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```js
try {
    await foo();
    await bar();
} catch (error) {
   console.error(error)
}
```

Comment: But this way if foo throws an error you will never reach bar right ? You too won't know which function has thrown the error. Am i missing something ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.